# Firebase Auth error on Ionic 6 when launching on IOS

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic6

I'm experiencing an issue using firebase on ionic. This issue only pops up when I try to launch the app on IOS (device or emulators).

As soon as I press the button that should be triggering my auth subscribers, it throw this error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: An internal AuthError has occurred. (auth/internal-error).

I've checked my config. Actually firebase in initialized like this

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFireAuthModule,
AngularFireDatabaseModule,
AngularFireFunctionsModule,
AngularFireStorageModule
```

I've also tried using

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
```

But it wasn't working...

I'm really stuck and I need to find a solution as quickly as possible.

Tanks for your help

Comment: Same here! Any solution??? In my case it works when I launch it `ionic capacitor run ios -l --external` but doesn't work normal standalone way and throws `auth/internal-error`

Comment: Got any solution for auth/internal-error ?